# Facebook Giveaways

Tags: site-growth, small-communities, user-engagement, blog

So I've recently started a new gaming blog. I have nearly 100 Facebook likes and I seem to be getting some traffic across my website.

I recently ran a Facebook giveaway in which I asked users to Share a post for a chance to win some free games. This yielded very positive results, I gained 20 likes in the space of 3 days (not a lot but good for my current size/ambition). However after some reading Facebook do not allow this sort of Promotion.

Can anyone suggest alternatives or loop-holes to this rule?
If I said on my website that to enter you had to share the post rather than directly on Facebook would that be a loop hole?

I've had much more success with the giveaway approach than I did with the Facebook adverts and they were much cheaper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, Facebook wants you to pay to promote your page. I won't get into why this is good or not, but your normal social media promotional tactics [won't work as effectively unless you are willing to pay for promotion](http://www.jonloomer.com/2014/11/16/facebook-promotional-posts/).

That being said, well done Facebook ads can be very effective if you have the budget. Or, [with clever content and posting](http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/03/the-filtered-feed-problem/), you can effectively promote your page without paying for advertising.

However, many social media marketers are abandoning Facebook for friendlier platforms.

Depending on who your target audience is, perhaps Instagram or Tumblr might be better places to focus your posts, especially if they are very visual.

I haven't read any articles speaking about the difficulty of promoting on Instagram like I have Facebook.  However, [Instagram has already exceeded Twitter in users](http://www.pewinternet.org/2015/01/09/social-media-update-2014/).  [Instagram has 3X engagement vs Facebook](http://www.adweek.com/news/technology/instagram-marketing-quickly-catching-facebook-159249). And its clear that [some very successful Instagram channels are making lots of money](http://petapixel.com/2015/03/06/top-instagram-users-making-thousands-per-photo-by-promoting-products/).

You should test your results on multiple social media platforms.  You mentioned you have a separate website.  That suggests your ultimate measure of success is click-throughs to your site, or registrations in your blog community, not just Facebook likes. Try the same posts on Instagram, Facebook, Tumblr, and Twitter and see what gets you the most engagement, and most sign ups.

Be sure to wrap your URLs in a shortener like [Bit.ly](https://bitly.com/) or use [Google Site Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) (its free). If your blog site is based on WordPress, its site analytics are pretty decent too.